# Can't see objects created in Django-Mezzanine Admin site

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I just upgraded a website from Django 1.7/Mezzanine 3 to Django 1.8/Mezzanine 3. After doing so, I discovered that the admin site showed none of the previously created objects from my apps, even though they exist in the database and on the live site.

When I inspect the object in my browser, it doesn't seem like the database is being searched at all. This affects all of my apps, plus the User app native to Django. It does *not* affect the pages app, comments app, or blog post app native to Django.

I've tried deleting migration files, restarting the server, deleting and recreating the database, and dropping affected tables to recreate them.

There are no error messages, the page just looks like no one has created any objects yet. When you create a new object and save it, you still can't see them, even though the new object is live and in the database.

Comment: Are you running nginx? I had this and 404's when I had proxy_set_header Host enabled.

Comment: I'm using the built in dev server that Django comes with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out what the problem was. The templates in my project has a content block called 'main' in mimicking the native template files. I needed to give the content block a new name across the board instead because they were overwriting the Mezzanine templates somehow.